# How to read an excel file created by Microsoft Excel by CH376 IC?

Tags: file, microcontroller

In my embedded system I am using a [CH376 IC (PDF link)](https://www.mpja.com/download/ch376ds1.pdf) for file handling. I am able to detect a Flash Disk, but not able to read the excel file created by Microsoft Excel. The excel file is created on the PC and copied in the Flash Disk.

I want to create a database in an Excel file on PC and after creating it, I want to upload in to my embedded system for this I need read the file created.

Please help me to read the file.

Comment: welcome to SO, read once: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, please add what you have tried so far, what is an exact issue you are facing so that SO members can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

The `.xls` and `.xlsx` file formats are both extremely complex. Parsing them is unlikely to be feasible in an embedded environment. (In particular, `.xlsx` is a PKZIP archive containing XML data -- you will need a minimum of 32 KB of SRAM just to decompress the file containing the cell data, and even more to parse it.)

Use a different file format. Consider using `.csv`, for instance -- it's just a text file, with one row of data on each line, so it's pretty straightforward to work with.